# Как поменять местами цифры в числе без использования временных переменных?

Tags: pascal

Учитель задал нам задачу: на вход пятизначное число. Затем у этого пятизначного числа берутся первые два и последние два числа, затем меняются местами. Например: Input: 24158, Output: 58124. Если два передних и задних числа, а также число посередине будут занимать по одной переменной, всего будет 4 переменных. А у нас задание: сократить число переменных до 2-х! Т.е. 1-я переменная - само число, 2-я переменная - все действия внутри числа.

```
Program Z_1;

var
  x, a, b, c: LongInt;

begin
  Randomize;
  x := random(89999) + 10000;
  writeln('Число: ', x);
  a := x div 1000;
  b := x mod 100;
  c := x div 100 mod 10;
  writeln('Результат: ', b,c,a);
end.
```

Должно получиться:

```
Program Z_1;

var
  x, a: LongInt;

begin
  Randomize;
  x := random(89999) + 10000;
  writeln('Число: ', x);
  a := ... ;
  writeln('Результат: ', a);
end.
```

Подскажите, как можно сократить число переменных до требуемого?

Comment: Ловите подсказку - вы можете выполнять все действия сразу в одной строке, без временных переменных. Надо только правильно расставить скобки.

Comment: Какую нибудь другую подсказку? :) Верчу эти скобки уже час...

Comment: Ловите вторую подсказку - вы можете отредактировать вопрос и добавить в него свою попытку решения с пояснением почему вам кажется что она должна работать и почему она не работает как надо.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно последние две и среднюю цифру числа домножить на 1000, 100 соответственно.

```
var
x, a: LongInt;

begin
  Randomize;
  x := random(89999) + 10000;
  writeln('Число: ', x);
  writeln('1 место: ', x mod 100);
  writeln('2 место: ', x div 100 mod 10);
  writeln('3 место: ', x div 1000);
  a := ((x mod 100)*1000 + (x div 100 mod 10)*100 + (x div 1000));
  writeln('Результат: ', a)
end.
```

Пример работы:

```
Число: 54651
1 место: 51
2 место: 6
3 место: 54
Результат: 51654
```

Объяснение:
На 1 место должны встать последние 2 цифры числа (`51`), мы домножаем их на 1000, чтобы они как бы "встали на 1 место" (Итог этого умножения: `51 * 1000 = 51000`), середину числа (`6`) мы оставляем на своем месте, для этого мы домножаем на 100 (Итог этого умножения: `51000 + 600 = 51600`),
первые две цифры числа (`54`) просто перебрасываем в конец без умножения (`51600 + 54 = 51654`).
Результат: 51654